# Date Based Automated Actions in Rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, state-machine

I'm developing a Rails4 app and I have lots of date attributes in a model. For example;

```
first_payment_date
last_payment_date
first_application_date
last_application_date
first_result_validation_date
last_result_validation_date
```

etc.

I want to automate things a little bit and want my application act with these dates. For example, user's won't be able to do payment, after the last_payment_date, or they will not be able to make an application before first_application_date.

What is the best approach to plan this kind of thing? I heard about "state machines" and state_machine GEM but I'm not sure if it's the right thing for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these dates are in the `User` model, you can create several helper methods inside it to return `true` of `false` based on your conditions:

```
def can_deliver_payment?
  self.last_payment_date > Date.today
end

def can_make_application?
  self.first_application_date > Date.today
end

# etc
```

So now when you have an instance of `User`, you can check these conditions on a more readable way.

Comment: These dates are in my Examination model.